# How to completely override the style class in FXML?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8, fxml

I'm trying to style some buttons using css from fxml but it seems that the below tag just adds the new class to what has been already assigned to the control instead of completely overriding everything.

```
<Button styleClass="my-button" />
```

I've found this bug report @https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8128681, where developers suggest that both scenarios (override and add) should be supported. But right now, in JavaFX 8, I can't find a way to override style classes. Is there a way to do it without having to work around this with Java code?

Comment: What about overriding the css properties defined in modena css to cover all necessary properties?

Comment: This is a good idea, but I find it quite weird that we have to do that much boilerplate work when trying to do clean code through FXML while you just need 1 line of code in Java... partly defeating the purpose of FXML. Moreover, it's not future-proof. In future JavaFX versions, the default styling may be changed for something else than modena as already happened between JavaFX 2 and 8...

Comment: There's no way to do this in FXML (that I know of). I really think of FXML as being there to define layout anyway - in any real application you will need a controller class to define the event handling and, in most cases, to do some initialization work. It's pretty unusual to want to replace all the default styles with your own stylesheet, so I'm not too surprised there's no FXML support for this. Just add an `fx:id` and do `myButton.getStyleClass().setAll("my-button");` in the `initialize()` method.

Comment: I see. You confirm what I thought and eventually did. I still feel this solution to be a workaround though...